# Finding groups via set intersection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am interested in generalizing which sets are groups via set intersection.
I can see how potentially a set containing an infinite series of non-empty
nested sets (i.e. $X_{1} \subseteq X_{2} \subseteq X_{3} \subseteq \cdots$ where
$X_i = \{a_i\}$), but I'm wondering if there are more interesting cases related
to this particular operator. I was considering sets where we can make
$\emptyset$ the identity element, but I would also like to see more interesting
cases. Does anyone have suggestions on how I might find a general case for
the structure of the sets of these particular groups?

Comment: In the given example we have $X_1 = \{a_1\} \not\subseteq \{a_2\} = X_2$, contradicting the claim of nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of $X$ is a group under set intersection, $\cap$. Then, for any subset $A \subset X$, $\varnothing \cap A = \varnothing$, and so $A$ must be the identity element. But a group has precisely one identity element, so $X$ has just one subset, and hence $X = \varnothing$. Thus, the only such group is $(\{\varnothing\}, \cap)$.

On the other hand, for any set $X$, the power set $\mathcal{P}(X) := \{A : A \subseteq X\}$ is a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) under set intersection. (A semigroup is a set $S$ endowed with an associative binary map $S \times S \to S$.) The power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is also a semigroup under set union, $\cup$.